# Match files that do not contain a particular string

Tags: python, regex

How to match

```
aby_<ANYTHING>.csv
xyz_<ANYTHING>.csv
```

but not

```
aby_<ANYTHING>_Result.csv
xyz_<ANYTHING>_Result.csv
```

whereas `<ANYTHING>` can be any string using regular expressions?

Comment: What language/regex library? Can you use an inverted regex?

Comment: I'm using python standard regex lib.

Comment: What if <ANYTHING> happens to equal '_Result'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about :

```
'^(aby|xyz)_.*?(?<!_Result)\.csv$'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the regular expression

```
^.*(?!_Result)\.csv$
```

This will match any series of characters, then NOT the string "_Result", then the string ".csv". It will also expect the entire string to be matched.